# Mongo DB Write timeout

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does Mongo have any option using which update/insert operations can be timed-out? Is MaxTimeMS only supported by query operations or write operations as well?

Can wTimeout option be used for this? If write concern is set to the majority and a timeout occurs, does mongo roll back the changes? Even after timeout can it be written to other replicas?

If wtimeout with write concern majority guarantees that it is not written to the majority, can reading the database using read concern majority guarantees that records with timeout are not read?

my use case is I want to write some data within a certain interval and return a response with a guarantee on whether the data is written or not.

Answer (score 1):

That is a lot of questions for one question.

> Does Mongo have any option using which update/insert operations can be timed-out?

Yes

> Is MaxTimeMS only supported by query operations or write operations as well?

maxTimeMS is a cursor options, cursors are used for reading

> Can wTimeout option be used for this?

Yes, that's what wTimeout is for

> If write concern is set to the majority and a timeout occurs, does mongo roll back the changes?

No, when the timeout expires the operation is interrupted and the client notified of the timeout, no rollback occurs unless it was inside a transaction.  If the write has already occurred on the primary, it will still be replicated.

> Even after timeout can it be written to other replicas?

Yes, unless it was in a transaction

> If wtimeout with write concern majority guarantees that it is not written to the majority, can reading the database using read concern majority guarantees that records with timeout are not read?

wTimeout does not guarantee the write wasn't completed, so if it wasn't in a transaction, a future majority read could see it after it has replicated.

Comment: Thanks for answering, is there any way to set a timeout so that either we succeed in saving the document within a timeout or we timeout and have guarentee that we didn't save the document?

Comment: Use a [transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/#transactions)